# Informix Blob data

Tags: blob, informix, liquibase

I need to know if there is any possibility of passing null in blob data using insert statement in Informix.

I know there is an option of `LOAD FROM <FILE> INSERT INTO <TABLE>`

Which works well, but i am looking for some insert statment, because i am implementing liquibase and i am not finding any way to insert null or leave it in insert values so that it can accept null. This field is set to TRUE for null values.

Error I am getting is following

> [Error Code: -617, SQL State: IX000]  A blob data type must be supplied within this context.

Tried this

```
INSERT INTO informix.tti_key_store (id, code, description, value_asc, cts, active) 
VALUES 
(4, 'EVDSDEALER', 'EVDS Dealer Passphrase', 'nodYzUNAs+htD1Mng3hYYg==', DATETIME (2016-02-17 12:51:34.000) YEAR TO FRACTION(5), 'T')
```

Tried this

```
INSERT INTO informix.tti_key_store (id, code, description, value_asc, value_bin, cts, active) 
VALUES 
(4, 'EVDSDEALER', 'EVDS Dealer Passphrase', 'nodYzUNAs+htD1Mng3hYYg==', NULL, DATETIME (2016-02-17 12:51:34.000) YEAR TO FRACTION(5), 'T')
```

value_bin is a blob field set to NULL to true.

Comment: Which version of informix are you using?  What are the types of the columns involved? What values are you trying to insert? I did a test on informix 12.10 and i had no problem assigning null to a BLOB column (using dbaccess).

Comment: With `CREATE TABLE blobby(id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, data BYTE IN TABLE);`, I can run `INSERT INTO blobby VALUES(0, NULL);` without problem.  I assume that would work for TEXT style blobs too.  BLOB and CLOB columns might be a different story — those are using 'Smart Blobs'.